# Is it possible for a component to look up its module heirarchy?

Tags: angular

Say that I have routes and routing modules defined like:

```
  {
    path: '',
    canMatch: [ () => inject(AGuard).canMatch() ],
    loadChildren: () => import('./a.module').then(m => m.AModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canMatch: [ () => inject(BGuard).canMatch() ],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./b.module').then(m => m.BModule),
  },

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [ARoutingModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class AModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class BModule {}

...

const aRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'somewhere', 
    component: SomeComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(aRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ARoutingModule {}

const bRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'elsewhere', 
    component: `
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(bRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class BRoutingModule {}
```

If both `SomeComponent` and `SomeOtherComponent` internally make use a shared component, is there any way for that shared component to be able to perform introspection and determine whether it was rendered from `AModule` or `BModule` ?

Comment: You can do this by using dependency injection and the way components are organized in a tree structure. Basically, you can put a service into your shared component to get info about the module it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a way to achieve this could be to have a specific provider set on each module for example.

```
const MODULE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('module-token'); 

@NgModule({
  imports: [ARoutingModule],
  providers: [{provide: MODULE_TOKEN, useValue: 'moduleA'}],
})
export class AModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ARoutingModule],
  providers: [{provide: MODULE_TOKEN, useValue: 'moduleB'}],
})
export class BModule {}

@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
   private readonly module = inject(MODULE_TOKEN); // either 'moduleA' or 'moduleB'
}
```

This way you'll be able to tell who is your module.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for my use case...  For example, if an HTTP interceptor is added to the providers of app.module, and that interceptor were to inject MODULE_TOKEN, it will not be found because it won't be available from its  injector.